# I have an if statement nested in a for-in loop that evaluates incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, for-loop

I'm using a for-in loop to get each object out of a dictionary of objects (passingObservations) and placing certain ones in an array of objects. It checks for a specific NSString @Property of the object and see if it is equal to another NSString. When equal, it places the object into schoolMArray. The if statement evaluates TRUE for the first run through the for-in loop and adds the object to the schoolMArray. On successive loops through the for-in, it evaluates FALSE. It shouldn't be doing that though. I've put in exact copies of the same object and it still evaluates the second object as FALSE.

```
for (NSString *key in keysArray) {
    ObservationData *obj =  [self.passingObservations objectForKey:key];
    if (obj.districtName == self.passingDistrict) {
        [schoolMArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare two objects. Use `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: never use == for strings use isEqualToString instead

Comment: Don't compare strings using '=='. Use `isEqual:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compared objects for equivalence using `==` rather than `isEqual:` (or, in the specific case of strings, `isEqualToString:`).

Comment: == is only for int or something?

Comment: @user3574030: `==` is a general equality operator, but it doesn't do anything special for objects. Objects are always referenced by pointers, so `==` compares the pointers to see if they point to the same address. Basically, it tells you whether it's *the same object* rather than merely whether the objects are equivalent. What you have are two strings containing the same text, not two references to the same string.

Comment: Thanks for that Chuck! That makes perfect sense.